# Check this with unmarked checkbox if

Tags: php, ajax, checkbox

I am doing an insert with PHP and AJAX with an insert. This is the code:

```
<input type='checkbox' id="moralibro" name="moralibro" value="mora">  
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('.error').hide();  
    $(".eliminarp").click(function() {  
        //Obtenemos el valor del campo mora  
        var moralibro = $("input#moralibro").val();  
        //Construimos la variable que se guardará en el data del Ajax para pasar al archivo php que procesará los datos  
            var parent = $(this).parent().attr('id');  
        var service = $(this).parent().attr('data');  
        var dataString = 'id='+service + '&moralibro=' + moralibro ;  
        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "eliminarprestamo.php",  
            data: dataString,  
            success: function() {              
                $('#delete-ok').empty();  
                $('#delete-ok').append('<div class="correcto">El prestamo se a eliminado correctamente a id='+service+'.</div>').fadeIn("slow");  
                $('#'+parent).fadeOut("slow");  
                //$('#'+parent).remove();  
            }  
        });  
    $('#categoria-registrar')[0].reset();  
        return false;  
    });  
});  
</script>
```

This is the file where does the insert eliminarprestamo.php

```
if (isset($_POST['moralibro']))  
{  
 $query = "INSERT INTO multas_estudiante(cedula_estudiante)   
  VALUES ('12345')";  
  $result = pg_query($query) or die('ERROR AL INSERTAR DATOS: ' . pg_last_error());  
}
```

I have tried `if (isset ($ _ POST ['moralibro']))` but still makes the insertion unchecked the checkbox, also with `if ($ _ POST ['moralibro']! = "")`

No more putting it, is affected in some AJAX?

Comment: Well what is the value of `$_POST['moralibro']` ? (in the php script)

Comment: You could try: `if(isset($_POST['moralibro']) && !empty($_POST['moralibro']))  ` to check whether the value is _actually_ passed. It is possible that the checkbox is passed with an empty value if unchecked, which would make `isset() => true`.

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['moralibro']) && $_POST['moralibro'] == "mora")  {/*...*/}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_POST['moralibro']` will always be set because if theres no value it will be `""` or a blank string.

Change this:

```
if(isset($_POST['moralibro']))
```

to this:

```
if(!empty($_POST['moralibro']))
```

Also. I noticed that your `input` has a static value of `"mora"` . If this value is always there without being deleted, then the insertion will always happen. What conditions do you need in order for the insertion to happen?

---

**UPDATE:**

Since you said the condition depends on whether the checkbox is checked or not, then you need to code this in the front-end since you are sending an AJAX call.

The way to do that is like this:

```
var moralibro = "";
var $m_input = $("input#moralibro");
if ($m_input.is(":checked")) {
    moralibro = $m_input.val();
}
var dataString = 'id='+service + '&moralibro=' + moralibro ;
```

Once you do this, you will either send a blank string or `"mora"` to PHP which should then be able to be picked up by `empty()`

Comment: the condition is that if not checked the checkbox no insertion is done, but if you fly so if the inclusion is done

Comment: and probe, delete the "value =" and the like, always perform the insertion

Comment: check my updated answer (you might need to refresh your page)

Comment: Thank you very much, I worked perfectly , Gracias !!

Comment: Awesome. Im glad I was able to help :)